# Kendo ui MVVM datepicker localization issue

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui

I'm trying to use datetime picker in an observable mvvm view model in a french app.

Even If I initialize culture of kendo the  drop down calendar still in English.

Is it possible to obtain months and weekdays in french ?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following lines to the related View or _Layout file:

```
<script src="~/.../cultures/kendo.culture.fr.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/.../messages/kendo.messages.fr-FR.min.js"></script>
```

Then call set the language via JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    kendo.culture("fr-FR");
</script>
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this?

```
$("#EventDate").kendoDatePicker();
    <input id="EventDate" type="text" value="08/04/2017 "  name="EventDate" >
```